# Background Task periodic

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm using C# and Windows Phone 8.1 as Universal App.
I have an application which can runs in the background. Here is my Background class:

```
 public sealed class RTask : IBackgroundTask
 {
     BackgroundTaskDeferral deferral_;
     public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
     {
         Debug.WriteLine("Background started");
         deferral_ = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
         Debug.WriteLine("GetDeferral");


         Debug.WriteLine("Retrieving data from url...");
         HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://mysite"));
         HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync();
         string pageSource = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
         Debug.WriteLine("PageSource Retrieved");
         pageSource = (System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(pageSource));
         pageSource = pageSource.Replace("\"", "'");
         //ParseHtml(pageSource);
         deferral_.Complete();
     }
 }
```

Here is my register code for register background:

```
    private async void RegisterBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string myTaskName = "RTask";
        foreach (var cur in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("cur.Value.Name:   " + cur.Value.Name);
            if (cur.Value.Name == myTaskName)
            {
                await (new MessageDialog("Task already registered")).ShowAsync();
                return;
            }
        }
        await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();
        BackgroundTaskBuilder taskBuilder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder { Name = "RTask", TaskEntryPoint = "MyTask.RTask" };
        taskBuilder.SetTrigger(new TimeTrigger(15, true));
        BackgroundTaskRegistration myFirstTask = taskBuilder.Register();

        await (new MessageDialog("Task registered")).ShowAsync();
    }
```

I need every 1 hour this background run and retrieving my data. Is this possible ? by according the code It's can't use periodic! I'v tested in the phone and just one time is working and then nothings can do.
If I didn't complete the deferral, is wrong with it?

In the Microsoft example of Background Task, they used a code 'ThreadPoolTimer'. in my case I need this or not?

Thannks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just make for periodic the trigger to `false`:

```
taskBuilder.SetTrigger(new TimeTrigger(60, false));
```

for oneshot it must be `true`, thus only one trigger.